# NiFi GenerateTableFetch does not store state per database.name

Tags: apache, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am testing out NiFi to replace our current ingestion setup which imports data from multiple MySQL shards of a table and store it in HDFS.

I am using `GenerateTableFetch` and `ExecuteSQL` to achieve this.

Each incoming flow file will have a `database.name` attribute which is being used by `DBCPConnectionPoolLookup` to select the relevant shard.

Issue is that, let's say I have 2 shards to pull data from, `shard_1` and `shard_2` for table accounts and also I have `updated_at` as `Maximum Value Columns`, it is not storing state for the for the `table@updated_at` per shard. There is only 1 entry per table in state.

When I check in Data Provenance, I see the shard_2 flowfile file getting dropped without being passed to ExecuteSQL. And my guess is it's because shard_1 query gets executed first and then when shard_2 query comes, it's records are checked against shard_1's updated_at and since it returns empty, it drops the file.

Has anyone faced this issue? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @mattyb Will you be able to help here? As an alternative, I am looking at saving last updated_at values manually in a file and using them in where clause for GenerateTableFetch.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to choose different databases via DBCPConnectionPoolLookup was added after the scheme to store state in the database fetch processors (QueryDatabaseTable, GenerateTableFetch, e.g.). Also, getting the database name differs between RDBMS drivers, it might be in the DatabaseMetaData or ResultSetMetaData, possibly in getCatalog() or getSchema() or neither.

I have written [NIFI-5590](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5590) to cover this improvement.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thanks for adding this to NiFi jira. For now I have added some workarounds using DistributedMapCache to handle this.